# How to reduce space between text box and chart without moving the text box?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, textbox

I am trying to plot various time series data in separate columns in a pandas dataframe with subplots() while automatically placing a text box for the data source at the bottom of the figure.

Everything works fine except that pandas/Matplotlib puts too much space in between the last plot and the text box at the bottom of the plots unless I reformat the dates in the index, for example, using `strftime()` which I don't wish to do. How do I expand the plots *only towards the bottom (I need the otherwise empty spaces to the left and right)* while keeping the text at the bottom and without making any modifications to the dataframe's index? I have tried `fig.tight_layout()` but it did not help much.

I understand the problem is triggered by the dataframe's index having an irregular date at the end (all other dates are quarter-ends) because the problem gets resolved if I exclude the last row in the dataframe being plotted or if I replace its date with the next quarter-end date.

Here is the code (I have modified the actual code and data as much as possible in order to simplify things) and its (undesired) output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

no = 54
dates = pd.date_range("20090101", periods=no, freq="Q")
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(no, 2), index=dates, 
    columns=["Istanbul", "Kyiv"])

no = 1
dates = pd.date_range("20220826", periods=no)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(no, 2), index=dates, 
    columns=["Istanbul", "Kyiv"])

df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2])

height = 8
fig, axes = plt.subplots(df1.shape[1], 1, figsize=(15, height))
fig.suptitle("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", y=1-0.2/height)
fig.text(0.1, 0.1/height, "Source: Lorem ipsum", fontsize=8)
fig.subplots_adjust(
    left=0.1, bottom=0.6/height, right=0.9, top=1-0.5/height
)
for i, col in enumerate(df1.columns): 
    df1.loc[:, col].plot(ax=axes[i],
        ylabel="(mm)", xlabel="", grid=True, legend=False,
        style=["o-"], sharex=True)
    axes[i].text(0.45, 0.87, f"{col}", \
        transform=axes[i].transAxes, weight=600,
        bbox=dict(facecolor="white", ec="white"), fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the underlying problem in my case was where the `fig.subplots_adjust()` was exactly used in the code. The code started working as I intended when I changed its place to right before `plt.show()`. Same issue with `fig.tight_layout()` if it is not placed right before `plt.show()` (plus `fig.tight_layout()` does not appear to give me the type of control I need on the figure at least as conveniently as `fig.subplots_adjust()`).

I checked the Matplotlib documentation for either method again and there does not appear to be an explicit warning on such proper (?) use of either.

Answer (score 2):

`fig.tight_layout()` reduced that space a lot for me:

```
fig.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

I placed this as an answer and not only as comment to be able to add the picture.
Maybe you can provide more info why `fig.tight_layout()` didn't provided what you were looking for.

Comment: Thx for the inspiration! It seems like the underlying problem was not the Matplotlib methods I have been using but exactly where I used them. See my answer for more details.